# How to remove the white lines on the sides of Tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ETC9.jpg)

As you can see in the screenshot, my program has white lines on the left and top, how can I remove them? I would like them not to be there at all.

```
import ctypes as ct
from tkinter import *
def dark_title_bar(window):
    window.update()
    DWMWA_USE_IMMERSIVE_DARK_MODE = 20
    set_window_attribute = ct.windll.dwmapi.DwmSetWindowAttribute
    get_parent = ct.windll.user32.GetParent
    hwnd = get_parent(window.winfo_id())
    rendering_policy = DWMWA_USE_IMMERSIVE_DARK_MODE
    value = 2
    value = ct.c_int(value)
    set_window_attribute(hwnd, rendering_policy, ct.byref(value), ct.sizeof(value))

win = Tk()

background_menu = PhotoImage(file="background-menu.png")
canvas_authorization = Canvas(win, width=1280, height=720)
canvas_authorization.grid()
canvas_authorization.create_image(640, 360, image=background_menu)
dark_title_bar(win)
win.geometry("1280x720")

win.geometry(str(win.winfo_width()+1) + "x" + str(win.winfo_height()+1))
#Returns to original size
win.geometry(str(win.winfo_width()-1) + "x" + str(win.winfo_height()-1))

win.geometry("1280x720")

win.mainloop()
```

Comment: I suspect that you just need to add a `borderwidth=0` option to your Canvas.

Comment: @jasonharper That helped me, thank you. Only I set it to -2, and then it worked the way I wanted it to

Comment: Set `highlightthickness=0` instead of `bd=-2`.

Comment: @acw1668 да, это работает лучше